# Navbar shows up without text/links on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, navbar

I can't understand why the navbar shows up without text or links (and not even the three line thingy) when I use my phone to access my website.

I tried adding media queries but it didn't seem to help.

How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the Bootstrap JavaScript file. It contains the Collapse plugin that makes the `navbar-collapse` work.

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

In addition, make sure it comes after the jQuery reference.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please write out the code I need to add explicitly? I'm new to coding, and it takes me ages to figure out a single step :)

Comment: Updated to include the script tag. If this works, please don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: That itself didn't work, but thanks anyway! Removing the viewpoint meta at the beginning did help though, but it meant that I can't use media queries. Will do for now though :)